# Can I generate Enterprise Architect diagrams from Python?

Tags: python, enterprise-architect

One of the first things I do on a new project is to knock up a quick script to parse a log file and generate  a message sequence chart, as I believe that picture is worth a thousand words.

New project, and it is mandated that we use *only* Enterprise Architect. I have no idea what its save file format is.

Is it possible to generate a file which will open in EA from Python?

If so, where can I find an example or a tutorial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EA is using a RDBMS to store it's repository. In the simplest case, this is a MS Access database renamed to `.EAP`. You can modify this RDBMS directly, but only if you know what you're doing. The recommended way is to use the API. Often a mix of both is the preferred way. You can use Python in both cases without issues.

Shameless self plug: I have published books about EA's internal and also its API on LeanPub.

Comment: I am so new that I didn't even know that there is an API :-/  Do you have a URL? If I see that the team might benefit from this, I will have the company buy your book :-) Maybe even a few copies :-)

Comment: Any hints as to exactly where? :-)

Comment: Where what? (sorry, I'm a bit confused at the moment...)

Comment: Exactly wher the references are, rather than just "on thid page somdwhere" (sorry, I am being lazy; I should search myself, but figured you could point directly there :-)

Comment: It's my own site. But here's the direct link: https://leanpub.com/InsideEA and https://leanpub.com/ScriptingEA